# Conic hull of S

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

There is a set S such that

$S = \{(x_1,x_2):(x_1-1)^2+x_2^2=1 \}$

I need to find the conic hull of this set. So, I know that the conic hull is basically defined as

$\mathbb{cone}(S)=\{ \sum a_i x_i: x_i \in S \ , \ a_i \geq 0\}$

I'm confused about how to proceed from here for the set mentioned above. I have to show that

$\mathbb{cone}(S)=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1>0\} \ \cup \ \{(0,0)\}  $

Comment: Is your definition of conic hull correct? In its current form it does not depend on $S$ at all.

Comment: @VHarisop Sorry that was a silly mistake. Made an additional edit as well as to what I have to show.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What strategies do you know for showing that two sets are equal?

Comment: @Brian I'm aware that you need to show them as subsets of each other but my confusion lies in the gap between the definition of the conic hull and the definition of S. Any hints would be appreciated as to how I can start in general to show the conic hull of a set using first principles (if such a general strategy exists)

Comment: I'm not sure how general the strategy is, but when you have a plane figure $S$, the set $\operatorname{cone}(S)$ amounts to the union of closed rays from the origin passing through the *convex* closure of $S$.  $S$ is such a simple figure, it should be easy to visualize this "cone".

Comment: Take any point in the right half plane.  Show that it can be obtained by scaling (with a nonnegative scaling factor) a point in the set $S$.  Polar coordinates might be helpful.